# Let H be a subgroup of a finite group G. Prove that if $gHg^{-1}$ is a subgroup of H, H is normal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Im trying to solve the following task.

[image]

a) is quite obvious, so no problems there.

**Im having troubles with b)**. I know a function which maps the entire group by $f(G)=gGg^{-1}$ is isomorphic, but im having troubles figuring out how this works on subgroups.

Surely, such a map of a subgroup H is not isomorphic to H, because that would make every subgroup normal in G?

So why does such a  map being a subgroup of S imply S is normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point is $gHg^{-1}\subset H$.

Since $gHg^{-1}\subset H$ for every $g$, replacing $g$ by $g^{-1}$ and applying $\gamma_{g}$ on both sides, we have $H\subset gHg^{-1}$ for every $g$.

Thus $gHg^{-1}=H$. Or, equivalently, $gH=Hg$.

However I do not get your trouble. $gHg^{-1}$ is always a subgroup of $G$ that is isomorphic to $H$, but $gHg^{-1}=H$ does not always hold when $H$ is not normal.

Answer (score 2):

If $aSa^{-1}\le S$ for every $a\in G$, then $S\le a^{-1}Sa$ for every $a\in G$ which is equivalent to $S\le (a^{-1})S(a^{-1})^{-1}$. Since every element of $G$ is $a^{-1}$ for some $a$, we have that $aSa^{-1}\le S\le aSa^{-1}$. Thus $aSa^{-1}= S$ for every $a\in G$, so $S$ is normal.